# How does Test and Set Instruction provide Bounded Waiting in below code?

Tags: operating-system, synchronization

In the below code how is bounded waiting condition satisfied ,I am unable to get the usage of these statements ,why have they applied the condition j!=i and j=(j+1)%n and then the condition mentioned inside if clause using (j==i),please clarify this ,according to me it should only check for waiting[j] , so as to confirm if any other process is waiting for lock or not ,I am unable to get the idea of working of this algorithm ,please explain it .

```
while ((j != i) && !waiting[j]) 
            j = (j + 1) % n; 
        if (j == i) 
            lock = false; 

do {
    waiting[i] = true;
    while (waiting[i] && test_and_set(&lock)) ;
    waiting[i] = false;

    /* critical section */

    j = (i + 1) % n;
    while ((j != i) && !waiting[j]) 
        j = (j + 1) % n; 
    if (j == i) 
        lock = false; 
    else
        waiting[j] = false;

    /* remainder section */
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bounded waiting** means no process should wait for a resource for **infinite** amount of time.

You have n processes, process i is currently executing, when it enters the critical section, it sets its waiting to false.

Now, what happens when process i has finished ?
Process i will look for an index j (process j) that is waiting to run in critical section. In other words, we are looking for a process that is waiting to enter the critical section that is different from the current process that ran in critical section.

`if (i==j)`, then no such process exists, we set lock to false. Otherwise, we set the process that is waiting to run and prevent starvation. And this way you satisfy Bounded Waiting.

This is achieved because you do a circular search, you first check processes

```
i+1, i+2, .... n, 0, 1, ... ,(i-1)
```

Comment: I still have confusion in the statement !waiting[j]  , why are we negating it when we move on to another process and it is interested in going inside the critical section , so it will set its waiting index to be true , so why are we negating it and moving onto the next process using j=(j+1)%n ?

Comment: And what is the difference between setting lock=false and waiting[j]=false ?

Comment: You negate it so as soon as you find a ready process, you start running that process in critical section.

Comment: Lock = false that means no process is in critical section. Whereas waiting = false means a process is not waiting to get in critical section.

Comment: Can you please explain negation of waiting[j] part again ,I am unable to get it . If a process is ready then its waiting[j] would be true and by negating it we would prevent the process from entering into the critical section ,which is not what we want

Comment: Yes, if waiting[j] == 'false', then you are not breaking the while condition. Unable to exit the while.

However, when waiting[j] == 'true', you break the while condition because you negate it.

Comment: So the last else condition basically says, if the next process is different from the current one and is waiting, set waiting[j] = false. WHY? We haven't executed its critical section yet.